# Comparing Javascript Objects by their ID to create a unique list in Angular/JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a call to the github API that gives me a an array of objects containing their commits. I want to loop through this and get a unique list of commitors and build it in the format:

```
{"id":temp,"label":temp,"type": "number","p": {} }
```

so I can graph it.

I wrote the following:

```
$scope.git = response.data;
    $scope.o=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.git,function(value){
      var temp = value.commit.author.name;
      if($scope.o.length==0){
        $scope.o.push({"id":temp,"label":temp,"type": "number",
            "p": {}
      })
      }
      else{
      angular.forEach($scope.o,function(ob){
        if(ob.id==temp){
          continue;
        }
        else{
          $scope.o.push({"id":temp,"label":temp,"type": "number",
              "p": {}
        })
      }
      });
}
})
```

This works but it is horribly inefficient. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object to check if an author has been already inserted into the list. Something like:

```
$scope.o = [];
var authors = {};
angular.forEach($scope.git, function(value){
    var temp = value.commit.author.name;
    if (authors[temp] === undefined) {
        $scope.o.push({"id":temp,"label":temp,"type": "number", "p": {} });
        authors[temp]  = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use libraries like underscore or lodash.one of the method that would be helpful here will be _.uniqBy.Here is the documentation for the same
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy